# RDP into ubuntu VM from macbook

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, macbook

I have an ubuntu VM that I usually SSH into, I have admin privs on this box.

I need to install some things on the box and I'd like to actually RDP into the VM rather than just use the command line.

Is there a way to do this so that I see GUI of the ubuntu VM?

Answer (score 1):

You could try running a VNC server to "get the whole desktop" under Linux.  Depending on what you are trying to do though, it could be orders of magnitude easier to simply make sure xauth is installed on the server (it probably already is), check that the config for sshd (/etc/sshd/ssh_config) allows X11 Forwarding, and then use an ssh client which will forward X Connections.  Simply log in - ideally using compression - and launch the "X" program you want to use - this connection should be forwarded across your SSH connection and the GUI interface will appear as a native program on your Mac.

Comment: which are some ssh client which will forward X connections?